# SSH.NET autentication fails with "openssh key type: ssh-rsa is not supported"

Tags: vb.net, ssh, sftp, private-key, ssh.net

I'm trying to send files using SFTP with public/private keys.  I've found examples in C# but very few in VB.  Trying to convert, I've got this far, but get an error at the first line despite being sure the key file is ok (works via FileZilla)

> openssh key type: ssh-rsa is not supported

Here's what I have:

```
Dim PKF As New PrivateKeyFile("C:\Users\jonfi\.ssh\id_rsa")
Dim PrivateKeyAuth = New PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(My.Settings.SFTPUser, PKF)
Dim ConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo(My.Settings.ServerAddress,_ 
    My.Settings.ServerPort, My.Settings.SFTPUser, PrivateKeyAuth)
 
Dim client As New Renci.SshNet.SftpClient(ConnectionInfo)

client.Connect()

' ...etc.
```

Note: I've hard coded the key path just for clarity.
Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run the C# version? Does it work?

Comment: I must confess, I've never run any C# programs, so I'd probably end up even more confused :-)